# Unattended software installation on Windows machine as normal user

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to install software on Windows machine as normal user and here is my script below:

```
cd C:\Users\scmadmin\Downloads\Auto-Installation
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.exe | ForEach {
   Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList '/S' -wait
}
```

I have the below files (exe's) in my folder to be installed

```
PS C:\Users\scmadmin\Downloads\Auto-Installation> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\scmadmin\Downloads\Auto-Installation


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         7/1/2019   7:19 PM        1447178 7z1900-x64.exe
-a----        6/24/2019  12:22 AM      567050280 Docker for Windows Installer.exe
-a----        6/30/2019  10:32 PM        1783200 Greenshot-INSTALLER-1.2.10.6-RELEASE.exe
-a----         7/1/2019   7:40 PM        3929368 npp.7.7.1.Installer.x64.exe
-a----        6/23/2019   6:56 PM       44801806 Udeler-Setup-1.7.0-windows-x64.exe
-a----        6/23/2019   6:54 PM       42034704 vlc-3.0.7.1-win64.exe
-a----         7/1/2019   7:18 PM       50266936 VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.35.1.exe
```

The issue is when I run my powershell script it produces errors as below,

```
PS C:\Users\scmadmin\Desktop> .\Install_All.ps1
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The operation was canceled by the user.
At C:\Users\scmadmin\Desktop\Install_All.ps1:3 char:4
+    Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList '/S' -wait
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

.
.
.
```

The problem is, I get pop up window, which I don't want. I want powershell to install the applications, end game is to have this PowerShell invoked by Ansible and installed on multiple machines.

How to get around with this? I did try with `-verb runas` but I have been tasked with this task as normal user and not as an administrator.

Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The pop up that shown is the UAC right?

Comment: Yes, correct. I don't want any pop ups, accepting the agreement, click next etc. Directly application being installed.

Comment: I tried your code with only 7z.exe found in Auto-Installation folder, and it worked fine without any error (ofcourse i have to press yes for the UAC popup). I suggest to do so for each installed (exe) and check which one is doing the error.

Comment: Every software will have a silent installation command separately which you need to script it in your master script. for example of 7z 'For exe installer: Use the "/S" parameter to do a silent installation and the /D="C:\Program Files\7-Zip" parameter to specify the "output directory". These options are case-sensitive.

For msi installer: Use the /q INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\7-Zip" parameters.'

Comment: As others already said you need to check each individual installer for what it accepts and invoke it depending on it (so a simple loop likely won't suffice) it also means you won't be installing those application to standard directories (C:\Program Files) as that needs elevated permissions. Maybe talk to whoever gave you that task and ask whenever he got a hint at how to accomplish it in your environment? Installing Docker without administrative privileges might be impossible. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1299061/install-doker-without-admin-rights).